# I want to get Name of currently logged in user from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to get user's name from my firebase database but I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

[here is my firebase database structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK7T9.png)

below is my code which is proffering the same error:

```
public class MyAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mSetupButton;
private EditText mSetupName;
private EditText mSetupBio;
private ImageButton mSetupImageButton;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private String mPostKey=null;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
    mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString(user_id);

    mSetupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountName);
    mSetupBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountBio);
    mSetupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accountButton);
    mSetupImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.accountImageButton);


    mDatabase.child(mPostKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String post_name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
            mSetupName.setText(post_name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Apparently the error is in getting user id.

Comment: the error indicates that there are no extras in the intent, have you successfully set the extras in the previous activity?

Comment: oops, i see, i'm not sending any extras in this activity, what do you think i should do now? @Wilik .

Answer (score 0):

just update or add as per your naming convention and your requirements in FirstScreen(i have almost done the required changes you need to make).

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, MyAccount.class);   
 String user_id;
 i.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the previous activity is `MainActivity`, then this is the code for it to put the extra to the intent

```
String mPostKey = // the post key value here

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAccount.class);
intent.putExtra("post_key", mPostKey);
startActivity(intent);
```

To get the extra in `MyAccount` activity, call

```
mPostKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("post_key");
```

By the way, I recommend you to change your database structure by putting the `uid` as the "post key", so it will be easier for you to read the user's information without retrieving the "post key"

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "0059HUGgfNcEyX73ZpTi6HQUscu1": {
            "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "image": "...",
            "name": "...",
            "phone": "..."
        },
        "other user's uid": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

With this database structure, you don't need the `mPostKey` anymore (don't need to put and get the intent extra). To get the user's information, you can just do this

```
mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()). addValueEventListener(eventListener);
```

Hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the currently logged in user from firebase simply use the following code:

```
String user_name=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. Did my answer helped you?